# express/nodemon server crashing on ubuntu digitalOcean

Tags: node.js, server, next.js

My server is a  2 GB Memory / 1 Intel vCPU / 25 GB Disk

Each time I restart the server it crashes as soon as a client tries to fetch anything, I'm on Next/Express/Mysql/Node stack , and I'm pretty sure that I have no syntax error, below is the output error:

```
0|yarn  | Killed
0|yarn  | error Command failed with exit code 137.
0|yarn  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

and these are the metrics of the server:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm still junior in server management, can anyone help, I'll provide all necessary details.
Thanks!

Comment: Error "Killed" most probably means there is not enough memory.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop  
top -b -n 1  for most active apps 
ulimit -a       for list of limits 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Mysql is on a separate server, the problem is not from mysql, the main problem is that next js on production when the server is on, is consuming about 2GB Ram which is think is a leak, a problem, it's not supposed to consume that much

Comment: And yes it is 25gb ssd

Comment: If you provide the data, there may be clues that next js is indeed not very efficient.  There may be next js or mysql configuration touches need for your minimal RAM server.

Comment: can you please specify more what should I provide you?

Comment: Yes, the list was requested on July 8 about 23:40 in the comment.